# Does an ad hoc, full backup, using Oracle RMAN, flag files, so they are not backed up by the regular backup?

Tags: oracle, backup, rman

If I run a simple RMAN full backup, ad hoc, outside of the regular backup scheduled, does that flag files so when the regular backup runs, that regular backup won't get some of the log files?

For example,

```
RMAN> Backup Database;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Overview of Backup Optimization](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/bradv/configuring-rman-client-basic.html#GUID-ABA3E439-57C2-4AE7-BCEF-39A6663E7AA2)

> When you enable backup optimization, the BACKUP command skips backing
>   up files when the identical file has been backed up to the specified
>   device type.
>
> ...
>
> RMAN uses backup optimization when the following conditions are true:
>
> - The CONFIGURE BACKUP OPTIMIZATION ON command has been run to enable backup optimization.
> - You run BACKUP DATABASE, BACKUP ARCHIVELOG with ALL or LIKE options, or BACKUP BACKUPSET ALL, BACKUP RECOVERY AREA, BACKUP RECOVERY FILES,
>     or BACKUP DATAFILECOPY.
> - Only one type of channel is allocated, do not mix disk and SBT channels in the same backup command.

With backup optimization, the database will not backup the same, **identical** file more than once to the same device type.

Other than that, the files will be backed up by the regular backup as well.

Comment: Are you sure? The [description of the FULL parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/rcmrf/BACKUP.html#GUID-73642FF2-43C5-48B2-9969-99001C52EB50) of the BACKUP command says: 
"A full backup has no effect on subsequent incremental backups and is not considered a part of any incremental backup strategy."

Comment: @miracle173 Works as described: https://pastebin.com/hhBLKnPm With a retention policy of `redundancy N`, RMAN creates `N+1` copies: https://pastebin.com/Xb46E1s8

Comment: @miracle173 That is what I saw too.  I know in some backup systems once a file is flagged, it doesn't get backed up by the incrementals.

Comment: I'm confused.  I'd like to just check answered, but I do not know if I can run a backup without messing up the regular back up.